# Give Java application a Metro Look and Feel in Windows 8

Tags: java, swing, windows-8, windows-runtime, look-and-feel

I have already developed a Java application which is working well in Windows XP, Windows 7 & Windows 8 consumer preview. The application is developed using GWT, CSS3 with Spring framework,and built-in Jetty server which is used to launch the application using the Internet explorer.

After exploring throught the metro apps principles, i want to give my application users an extra benefit of using is as a [metro app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh852650)

I read about [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html), [gwt-explorer](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/). But still i'm not sure. Is there any other workaround with minimum code changes?

Thank you Mr.Andrew Thompson for helping me.

Comment: My trawl through the info. pages on [metro-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/metro-framework/info) & [metro-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/metro-ui/info) tend to suggest it is actually [winrt](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/winrt/info) that supplies 'Metro'.  Can someone more experienced with the MS frameworks clarify?  I added [tag:winrt] but have not yet removed [tag:metro-framework].

Comment: Are metro style apps all web based?

Comment: Is this a web app. or desktop app.?

Comment: @Thihara: No; in fact, none* of them are.

Comment: HTML 5 and Javascript seemed to imply that... Anyway there are tools that will convert your SWING apps to web based applications. However I'm not sure that is what you want...

Comment: @Thihara: HTML5 and JavaScript can be used to create Metro apps and no, the OP probably doesn't want a web app. Plz read: [tag:winrt]

Comment: Hmm I did. What are the chances of a Metro style look and feel coming to Java? That will make most lives easier...

Comment: I have made extensive edits to your question since there seems to be much confusion as to whether this is a web or desktop app.  Of course, I might be the one who is confused.  Please check the edited version carefully, as well as the link and the info. pages for each tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could mimic Metro style in a Java application. Here is an effort using the JavaFX UI framework:

http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/metro/

You can only use such applications in the desktop environment of Windows 8 though, not in the metro environment. But that could still be useful, depending on the case.

Answer (score 10):

> Metro style look and feel coming to Java?

I thought this was more to do with the Pluggable Look & Feel.  Well don't wait, create!  See:

- [How to Write a Custom Look and Feel](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html)
- [Creating a Custom Look and Feel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html)
- [The Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Comment: Can anyone help me with a workaround?

Answer (score 9):

You guys all need to re-read the post again or fully understand the technologies before you jump all over this guy. He is saying he developed in GWT which is Java compiled to HTML/Javascript which **does** work in metro.

I know this is an old thread but I can't stand when people do that, it just makes it more confusing for other people reading this question.

Comment: I'm planning to build a Proof Of Concept - native bridge using JNA or similar. If I manage to display a Toast, I'll post an answer here.

Answer (score 5):

So I read the question again, and realized you're asking about how to get 'Metro' look and feel to a web application, and not a classic Java App..

Try this one http://metroui.org.ua/
Package provide a set of CSS and Javascript files to help your site have the metro look and feel.

HTH

---

**::OLD ANSWER::**

Java is NOT JavaScript in the same way that a CAR is not a CARpet.

Your best bet is to do your UI and parts that need to interface with the OS in a .NET language (C# or VB) and try to convert your existing Java code in to JSharp.

I cannot confirm that JSharp is supported to be used in a Metro Style app though.

Other options is that, if you have a web based alternative to your app, then you may have a better shot trying to convert than into a HTML/JavaScript Metro app.

Simply, Java and Metro, just don't get along, and they probably never will.